# Abelian subvarieties corresponding to vector subspaces

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry, abelian-varieties, algebraic-surfaces, hodge-structure

Let $S$ be a connected smooth projective surface.

Let $C$ a smooth curve on $S$

In page 9 of the paper "https://arxiv.org/abs/1704.04187v1" a read the following:

Let
\begin{equation*}
    r: C\rightarrow S
\end{equation*}
be the closed embedding of the curve $C$ into $S$.

Let
\begin{equation*}
    {r}_*:H^1(C,\mathbb{Q})\rightarrow H^3(S,\mathbb{Q}),
\end{equation*}
the Gysin homomorphism in cohomology groups whose kernel is $H^1(C,\mathbb{Q})_{van}$, the group of vanishing cycles; and let $B$ be the subvariety in $J=J(C)$, the jacobian of the curve $C$, corresponding o the $\mathbb{Q}$-vector subspace $H^1(C,\mathbb{Q})_{van}$ of $H^1(C,\mathbb{Q})$.

I would like to know  what does it mean "$B$ be the subvariety in  $J$ corresponding o the $\mathbb{Q}$-vector subspace $H^1(C,\mathbb{Q})_{van}$"? I mean how  $B$ and $H^1(C,\mathbb{Q})_{van}$ are related?

I already  know  the relation between subvarieties of the Jacobian $J$ and Hodge substructures of  $H^1(C,\mathbb{Z})$. So, maybe in order to obtain  the $\mathbb{Q}$-vector subspace  corresponding to $B$, I need first to have its corresponding Hodge substructure in $H^1(C,\mathbb{Z})$ and then just tensor it  with $\mathbb{Q}$? Am I right?

Comment: The homomorphism denoted by $r_*$ here, the Poincare dual of the "usual" pushforward homomorphism on homology, is a morphism of weight one (rational) Hodge structures.  The kernel is also a weight one (rational) Hodge structure, which thus corresponds to an isogeny class of complex tori.

Comment: Dear @JasonStarr Thank you for your comment!. Any reference  where I can read in a more detailed way the correspondence between (rational) Hodge structure and an isogeny class of complex tori?